# Who saw rasulullah in their dreams?

Tags: hadith, dream

It's pretty well-acknowledged that many companions (radiallahu anhum ajmaeen) like Bilal, Uthman ibn Affan, and others saw rasulullah (salallahu alayhi wa sallam) in their dreams.

Some authors contend that seeing rasulullah in dreams is not necessarily a bishara, and mention that several of the kuffar saw rasulullah in their dreams, like Abu Jahl.

Are there any confirmed incidents in the sunnah that mention if any kuffar saw rasulullah in their dreams? Bearing in mind that I'm looking for hadith specifically; Shaytan commonly appears in dreams of certain demographics of Muslims as a clean shaven, green-turban-clad man claiming to be rasulullah. I'm not looking for rhetoric or incidents out of hadith.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** This answer doesn't answer the question but tries to explain why there hasn't been any YET.

It's been more than 2years since this question is asked. No answer till now implies, no one has particularly searched all the Hadith books just to cherry pick incidents where kuffar  saw Prophet (pbuh) in their dreams. And even getting such things is difficult, because what you've asked doesn't belong to "Words of Prophet(pbuh)" or "Important Rulings Given by Companions" categories.

Let me guess, the most likely reason this question was put up because, you want to find instances where Prophet(pbuh) appeared to Non believers(kuffar) stating that might be Devil(shaytan) because Prophet(pbuh) appeared to Kuffar and when he appears to his companions then likely indicating something good(Bashara)...

Many Christians even today report that they saw Jesus(pbuh) in their dreams. And that becomes a 1 hour story in their churches and congregations.

I'll give you my example, I sometimes see my grandma in mah dreams, indicating that I'm going away from God, and thereby reminding that I should turn towards God.(Irja'u il-Allah) Or, I can say, she is not indicating me, but it is me who took her appearance as such a sign.

---

Let's talk some psychology...

When you spend your day thinking positively or when you end up doing too many bad things and you're guilty of something or when you've to take an important decision and you could not decide for yourself ... etc., people report such instances of special appearances of people whom they're very attached to(knowingly or unknowingly). They need not know them personally. When those special people appear to them, they consider as messages from divine Spirit(Bashara) indicating them they're doing good, or they should feel sorry about and do some good or to incline on one side while taking a decision(respectively).. etc.

Likewise the opposite, when you hate someone so much that they start haunting you even in dreams. Like the example you mentioned when Abu Jahl(the worst enemy of Prophet(pbuh)) was a kuffar and yet saw the Prophet(pbuh) thereby indicating that it might be shaytan. How can you for sure decide that the one appearing in someone's dreams is that person at all or shaytan. Many people dare not to question such things, "How can prophet(pbuh) or any other person intentionally come in one's dreams?" - HOW?

Ever heard this line...??? "Men are given free will". So, when man is awake and chooses to always think about a particular person so much that, that particular special person starts appearing in dreams, it is completely his choice, ultimately he's choosing what to dream(to some extent).

But, in the light of Qur'an, we hear an example of Dream interpretations by Prophet Joseph(Yusuf)(pbuh) in chapter(Surah) 12. He had the ability to interpret dreams 'CORRECTLY'. You might've even heard of this term called 'Déjà vu'. In short, it is "You see what you dreamt of(or it seems like you've been through a situation before)". Many people experience that.

We all know that it is the creator who decides the fate, and if dreams can at all be interpreted or can be seen to come true, then the creator is showing a snapshot of the future to you through your dreams. Thereby indicating that it is the creator who decides what we dream of course through people whom the dreamer is very much concerned about.

But, it is not always like that as you yourself said.

---

> Shaytan commonly appears in dreams of certain demographics of Muslims as a clean shaven, green-turban-clad man claiming to be rasulullah.

Of course, shaytan is man's best friend. He can not only appear to people of Islamic countries as "clean shaven, green-turban-clad man" but also as neatly pressed dressed dignitary to westerners and also in a cool Asian attire to Asians and  such. He can in any form deceive you. I recommend you to watch this '[Getting started with Jinn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0usGDDlyK7A)' video by Dr. Bilal Philips who's done a considerable research in this topic.

**To conclude,** dream interpretation is a separate branch of science(religion). Special people appear in dreams because we usually think about them. We don't do what our dreams ask us to do, we do what our brains ask us to do(through dreams). And we try to train our brains what is right & what is wrong according to Qur'an and Hadith.

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score -2):

Your saying that shaytan disguising as our Prophet Muhammed Salellahu Alaihi wasallam is not true as in a few authenticated narrations included in sahih Muslim it states that our Prophet SAW had said that if so and so states to have seen him in his dream then it is true as shaitan can not take the form of Prophet Muhammed.

Comment: That is only the case for those who know how he looks. Many people do not know how the prophet looks exactly. The hadith says Shitan can't imitate the prophet, but this doesn't help if you don't know how he looks like.

Comment: No one knows how he looks, but if anyone sees the Prophet Muhammed SAW in his dreams he has that feeling in his heart that that is the Prophet!! You get a feeling when you see... I had not seen Isa AS but I did see him in my dreams and I got that feeling that it is Isa AS!

Comment: That hadith was meant for those who saw him (his companions). A feeling is not enough, you need to research and insure that he 100% looks like what is reported by various hadith.